# libs for generating DSL ASTs in python, tree traversers/rewriters, advanced dispatch/pattern matching?

Tags: python-3.x, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, dispatch

I'm still trying to figure out a way to implement a DSL efficiently in Python, I've settled for ANTLR 4.X for parser generation, my problem now is that the DSL is big and I need an efficient way to specify the AST for my DSL.

I've taken a look at macropy which would be ideal if only it were python 3.6.x compatible and not 2.7.x-only.

I've found the iAST package which allows to generate python classes from a Zephyr ASDL spec. Are there any other better options I should know about for generating ASTs from an ADT spec ?

Also, I've looked at several dispatch libraries in order to write AST traversers and rewriters in a modular and composable way (trying to avoid the naive method-naming-based visitor pattern), I cannot decide which to choose (PEAK-rules? multimethods? functools dispatch?).
I'd like to venture into a mixture of type and predicate-based dispatch which could take me closer to proper pattern matching, however all these libs seem rather sketchy and fragile...

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: just found out that macropy was forked and updated to work with python 3.5+ :)

https://github.com/azazel75/macropy

it has a peg parser generator, scala-like case classes and pattern-matching, ideal for building transpilers in python